# Cannot convert object to primitive value error in react application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a simple react-spring boot application, but because of a GitHub issue I recreate my application starter files using IntelliJ and installed the node modules using the previous application's package.json file's dependency data.

If I use a collapsing navigation bar (hamburger bar-->responsive navbars which collapse in the mobile view) and click the hamburger button to see the nav links it gives me the below error. But all those things went well in the previous application.

````
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/js/src/collapse.js:346
  343 |   ...typeof config === 'object' && config ? config : {}
  344 | }
  345 | 
> 346 | if (!data && _config.toggle && /show|hide/.test(config)) {
      | ^  347 |   _config.toggle = false
  348 | }
  349 | 
View compiled
Function.each
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/webapp/front-end/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:381
  378 | if ( isArrayLike( obj ) ) {
  379 |     length = obj.length;
  380 |     for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
> 381 |         if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
      | ^  382 |            break;
  383 |         }
  384 |     }
View compiled
jQuery.fn.init.each
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/webapp/front-end/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:203
  200 | 
  201 | // Execute a callback for every element in the matched set.
  202 | each: function( callback ) {
> 203 |     return jQuery.each( this, callback );
      | ^  204 | },
  205 | 
  206 | map: function( callback ) {
View compiled
jQuery.fn.init._jQueryInterface [as collapse]
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/js/src/collapse.js:337
  334 | }
  335 | 
  336 | static _jQueryInterface(config) {
> 337 |   return this.each(function () {
      | ^  338 |     const $this   = $(this)
  339 |     let data      = $this.data(DATA_KEY)
  340 |     const _config = {
View compiled
HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/js/src/collapse.js:385
  382 |     const $target = $(this)
  383 |     const data    = $target.data(DATA_KEY)
  384 |     const config  = data ? 'toggle' : $trigger.data()
> 385 |     Collapse._jQueryInterface.call($target, config)
  386 |   })
  387 | })
  388 | 
View compiled
Function.each
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/webapp/front-end/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:381
  378 | if ( isArrayLike( obj ) ) {
  379 |     length = obj.length;
  380 |     for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
> 381 |         if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
      | ^  382 |            break;
  383 |         }
  384 |     }
View compiled
jQuery.fn.init.each
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/webapp/front-end/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:203
  200 | 
  201 | // Execute a callback for every element in the matched set.
  202 | each: function( callback ) {
> 203 |     return jQuery.each( this, callback );
      | ^  204 | },
  205 | 
  206 | map: function( callback ) {
View compiled
HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/js/src/collapse.js:381
  378 | const selector = Util.getSelectorFromElement(this)
  379 | const selectors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
  380 | 
> 381 | $(selectors).each(function () {
      | ^  382 |   const $target = $(this)
  383 |   const data    = $target.data(DATA_KEY)
  384 |   const config  = data ? 'toggle' : $trigger.data()
View compiled
HTMLDocument.dispatch
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/webapp/front-end/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5428
  5425 | event.handleObj = handleObj;
  5426 | event.data = handleObj.data;
  5427 | 
> 5428 | ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle ||
       | ^  5429 |  handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );
  5430 | 
  5431 | if ( ret !== undefined ) {
View compiled
HTMLDocument.elemData.handle
C:/Users/Hasindu/Documents/AF/Application Frameworks/online-fashion-store-master/src/main/webapp/front-end/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5232
  5229 | 
  5230 |        // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
  5231 |        // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
> 5232 |        return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
       | ^  5233 |          jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
  5234 |    };
  5235 | }
View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.```
````

Comment: started getting this error just today myself, wonder if it's some oddity in a new release of something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already used jquery 3.41 but I got the issue after moving my project files to another project so in a case of using jquery 3.41 still try and see by running the commands of  ,

**1)npm remove jquery**

**2)npm install jquery@~3.4.1**

**These commands solved my problem.**

Answer (score 72):

First, remove jQuery:

```
npm remove jquery
```

and then reinstall it:

```
npm install jquery@~3.4.1
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. I spend a whole hour on that wondering what happened. :( Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you, this was the same as what I did in the end to solve this matter.

Comment: Upvoted, but i would like to add that is needed to restart/rebuild. Either `npm run dev` or restart and again `npm run watch`.

Comment: Mention: It is now fixed in jquery 3.5.1, so `npm update` should fix it

Comment: 3.4.1 has an XSS vulnerability: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gxr4-xjj5-5px2. Use 3.5.1 instead.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem in a rails 6 project I was developing. I am using bootstrap 4.4.1 and had the exact same problem with my collapsing navigation bar: The navbar collapses but the hamburger button which appears on collapse was not clickable.

The solution: Downgrade jquery from 3.5.0 to 3.4.1. I did not look into the actual reason of the error for now.

To add more details, the jquery version should be updated in `package.json` dependencies and don't forget to run `yarn install --check-files` after you do this for the change to be applied.

Comment: I am currently using jquery 3.4.1

Comment: FWIW this is not working for me either. I was using WordPress which uses some old 1.x version, i swapped out for 3.4.1 and still seeing the issue. I think is related to something rather new as there are very similar posts within the past hour (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177140/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-convert-object-to-primitive-valuezone-evergreen-js1/61177579#61177579)

Comment: Locate your Jquery package in project node_modules, delete it and reinstall it using this command, npm install jquery@~4.3.1

Comment: I was pulling in 2 versions of jQuery, ignore the above, all is good!

Answer (score 20):

This is related to `jQuery 3.5.0.` It is a breaking change that affects many plugins. Temporarily reverting to a previous version of `jQuery (like 3.4.1)` fixed the issue for me.

or

Locate your Jquery package in project `node_modules`,  delete it and reinstall it using this command

```
npm install jquery@~3.4.1
```

Source: [jQuery Issue #4665](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4665)

Answer (score 5):

Like many others have said, I had the same issue with thanks to `jquery 3.5.0`.

It appears that this is now fixed with `3.5.1`

Answer (score 4):

I removed jQuery with `yarn remove jquery`, and then installed `yarn add jquery@3.4.1` to downgrade.

The issue was that 3.5.0 was still found in the yarn.lock file, thus the error was still occurring.

I had to add in package.json, outside of the `"dependencies"` section:

```
"resolutions": { "jquery": "3.4.1" },
```

Finally the error was gone.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. This was my issue as well, having 3.5.0 in my package-lock.json file. I have been racking my brain for the past hour trying to figure out why I was still getting that error.

Answer (score 3):

Open `package.json` and replace

```
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
```

with

```
"jquery": "3.4.1"
```

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30553#issuecomment-613558955)

Comment: I had the top option in my package.json file and was still having the error. Changing it to the option without the caret and recompiling assets fixed it for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Oranges13 It makes me so happy to know that I could help someone! Peace!

Answer (score 1):

Remove Jquery package from `node_modules` folder.

Then re-install it using this command.

```
npm install jquery@3.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either go back jquery v3.4.1 or recently they have released v3.5.1. This version is working fine. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery/v/3.5.1) is the npm package.