# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value(zone-evergreen.js:171)

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular9

In **Angular 9** (using Bootstrap 4 and Jquery 3.5.1). when clicking on bootstrap *collapse* button, I am getting an error on my browser console instead of a *dropdown* menu.

I really don't know where exactly the error came from.

```
Can't convert object to primitive value(zone-evergreen:171).


Uncaught Type Error: Cannot convert object to primitive value(zone-evergreen.js:171 )
    at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: This is caused by jQuery 3.5.0 , downgrade your jquery version to 3.4.1 for a temporary fix

Answer (score 107):

This issue seems to be related to jQuery 3.5.0. It is a breaking change that affects many plugins. Temporarily reverting to a previous version of jQuery (like 3.4.1) fixed the issue for me.

Source: [jQuery Issue #4665](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4665)

**Update:**

jQuery 3.5.1 reverts the breaking change and should be safe to use.

Announcement: [jQuery 3.5.1 Released: Fixing a Regression](https://blog.jquery.com/2020/05/04/jquery-3-5-1-released-fixing-a-regression/)

Comment: I have the same issue, and FWIW this suggestion is not working. I was using WordPress which uses some old 1.x version, i swapped out for 3.4.1 and still seeing the issue. I think is related to something rather new as there are very similar posts within the past hour (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176484/how-to-solve-cannot-convert-object-to-primitive-value-error-in-react-application)

Comment: I was wrong, nevermind the last comment, I was pulling in 2 versions of jQuery

Comment: In my case, my bootstrap accordion stopped working.  That is, clicking on a card header did not open the card.  `npm i jquery@3.4.1` fixed my `Cannot convert object to primitive value` problem.

Comment: This answer saved my bacon.  Thank you so much!  My package,json had "jquery": "^3.2.1".  Changing it to "jquery": "3.2.1" solved the problem.

Comment: Bootstrap documentation also recommends a version of 3.4.1 [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Comment: I am already using  "jquery": "^3.4.1" with "bootstrap": "^4.3.1" and bootstrap accordion works fine in my local environment but somehow it is breaking on development environment. And I face same error as shows in question.

Comment: Fixed my problem. Also keep in mind if you use npm, set the version to "3.4.1" (not "^3.4.1" as it will probably hold the old version) then run `npm install`.

Comment: Ran into this just now with a fresh install of Laravel using the Bootstrap UI components. Setting package.json to ask for jQuery 3.4.1 fixed it.

Comment: btw, it took  me a while to find jquery3.4.1... it can be found here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js and here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js (i got them from https://blog.jquery.com/2019/05/01/jquery-3-4-1-triggering-focus-events-in-ie-and-finding-root-elements-in-ios-10/). Oh, and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

They have a fix for that now (see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/65e909844c2d064606217b47e92eff12ebdb79de) if you are up to building your own jquery using node/npm then just download the commit on the link above and build it.

What I did was to edit my jquery.min.js (3.5.0)

Steps I did:

1. search for the line: `return t||(t=Object.create(null)` it's in Line 2,Column 32856
2. replace `Object.create(null)` with `{}`

and that's it so far so good

Answer (score 0):

At today's answer, `jquery` already fix the issue and you don't have to do any regression.

Just uninstall `jquery`, install it again and the latest **3.5.1** version, released on 2020-05-04, should fix the problem - for me it did, and I'm also using **Angular 9** and **BS4***
A beauty - back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this issue too, so moved from 3.5.0 to 3.5.1 (latest) and error is gone