# Bootstrap navbar toggler working only on first click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

My navbar collapses but the hamburger button which appears on collapse is not clickable. I am using Bootstrap 4.3.1 & Rails 6. I downgraded jQuery from 3.5.0 to 3.4.1. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178129/12099013) by doing `yarn remove jquery` & `yarn add jquery@3.4.1` and then `yarn install --check-files`.  I also deleted the jquery folder in app/node_modules and reinstalled it with the previously mentioned code but it did not change anything. I just want to mention that even after reinstalling jQuery, the folder was not added in node_modules. I do not know if this is important, but my jQuery animations still work however.

Here is my partial `_app_nav`:

```
<%= render :layout => "layouts/base" do %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a href="<%= posts_path %>" class="navbar-brand"><%= image_tag image_path('logos/edukado_white.png'), width: 140, class: 'mr-2'%></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(posts_path) %>">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<%= posts_path %>">Accueil</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(new_post_path) %>">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<%= new_post_path %>">Publier</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(new_user_invitation_path) %>">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<%= new_user_invitation_path %>">Inviter</a>
        </li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(posts_user_path(current_user)) %>">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%= posts_user_path(current_user) %>">Mes publications</a>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <%= render partial: 'layouts/navbar' %>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

My application.js file:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.


// ***** START: ADDED BY KisoThemes *****
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery")
// ***** END: ADDED BY KisoThemes *****

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
// ***** START: ADDED BY KisoThemes *****
require("bootstrap")
require("metismenu/dist/metisMenu")
require("jquery-slimscroll")
require('bootstrap-switch')
require('chartjs')
require('jquery-countdown')
require('jquery-countto')
require('cd-easypiechart')
require('fastclick')
require('object-fit-images')
require('flot/source/jquery.canvaswrapper');
require('flot/source/jquery.flot');
require('gmaps.core')
require('jasny-bootstrap')
require('jvectormap')
require('jquery-parallax.js')
require('code-prettify')
require('prismjs')
require('sparklines')
// ***** END: ADDED BY KisoThemes *****




// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
require("kiso_themes")
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I would try disabling turbolinks and see if that solves the problem, you can do this by commenting out the require turbolinks in the application.js. If this does solve the problem, then you know it's related to turbolinks and not your bootstrap code. Can you test and report back the result

Comment: Ok so I commented this line `// require("turbolinks").start()` in application.js & restarted my server. The problem is still here...

Comment: Ok so at least we ruled that out, so next question, when you toggle the sidebar, do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Did you checked source panel in chrome developer tool? You can see which javascript files are included in that page.

Comment: I do not get any errors in the browser console when I toggle the navbar @Brad.
@SeoungHoJeoung I am not sure if that is what you are looking for but it is calling in packs/js a file called application. I searched for jQuery in it and this is the first line where I found it: `/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(this, __webpack_require__(/*! jquery */ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js")))`.

Comment: I also just realized that some of the dropdowns buttons are not working properly when the navbar is collapsed. I do not know if this is related somehow but I just wanted to make sure that you guys were aware of this problem.

Comment: I had an issue with turbolinks in my js manifest file. `application.js`. Try removing the .start() from `require("turbolinks").start()`.  It could also be the order of your script files.  Make sure some files aren't dependent on the others.  EX: jQuery needs to be required before files that use JQuery.

Comment: Ok so I modified my post to add my `application.js` file @Thomas. I removed the `.start()` after `require("turbolinks")` (not shown in the post) but it did not work. You can also see how jQuery is being called before any other file.

Answer (score 1):

Using bootstrap 5 and Rails 6, i fix it by changing this in the button class

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
```

to this

```
data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
```