# How to fix cannot convert object to primitive value in collapsing of navigation bar using React JS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I currently have problem regarding on navigation bar, when i try to collapse the browser and try to open the navbar it not works, the console found an error and it says cannot convert object to primitive value. I already try to downgrade my jQuery to **"jquery": "3.4.1",** and it not works also.
I found same question on my problem [Cannot convert object to primitive value error in react application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176484/cannot-convert-object-to-primitive-value-error-in-react-application) however i tried to configure it not works on my project.

I used Laravel 5.7 and react front end

Error:

[image: error found]

Here is my bootstrap navigation code:

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">

                <div className="navbar-toggler-right">
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                </div>




                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column " id="navbar">

                    <ul className="navbar-nav  w-100 justify-content-center px-3">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul className="navbar-nav justify-content-center w-100 bg-secondary px-3">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>


                </div>

            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, but I am using Laravel.

Have you included in the head section or script section?

For instance, you are using `jquery": "3.4.1`
You may need to put the

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```