# Bootstrap hamburger menu icon won't collapse

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add this bootstrap nav menu to my Laravel application, but in smaller screensize when I click on the hamburger icon it won't open.

I checked similar questions here and tried the solutions but none of them worked for me.

I also checked, bootsrap css and js are properly included in the document, in my footer first comes jquery, then popper then bootstrap.js.

Here is my header code:

```
<header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}"><img src="{{ asset('public/assets/frontend/images/logo.png') }}"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('frontend.courses') }}">Courses</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-red" href="{{ route('login') }}">Sign In</a></li>
                            @else
                                @if(Auth::user())
                                    <li class="nav-item logged-in">

                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Dashboard
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                                @if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('admin') }}">Admin</a>
                                                @endif
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Profile</a>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Log out</a>
                                                     <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                        @csrf
                                                    </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </li>
                                @endif
                        @endguest

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
```

I also have these error messages in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
>       at RegExp.test ()
>       at HTMLDivElement. (collapse.js:346)
>       at Function.each (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)
>       at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)
>       at S.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (collapse.js:337)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (collapse.js:385)
>       at Function.each (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)
>       at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (collapse.js:381)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61198996/7133015

This is an incompatibility between bootstrap and kquery (3.5.0). needed to switch back to jquery 3.4.1